# lxml: How do I pass a (python) tuple/list to etree.XSLT() object to dynamically generate the xml from the xslt?

Tags: python, xml, list, xslt, lxml

lxml's documentation talks about `passing` parameters for the xslt. Here it is: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#stylesheet-parameters But how do I pass a `sequence/tuple/list` to the same `transform` method so that my xslt will catch it and render it (to an xml) using `xsl:for-each`

If I pass it like this:

```
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_content)
transform(input_xml_content,
          **{'items':('item1', 'item2')})
```

All I get is:

```
  File "xslt.pxi", line 519, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:119769)
  File "xslt.pxi", line 642, in lxml.etree._convert_xslt_parameters (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:120985)
  File "xslt.pxi", line 634, in lxml.etree._convert_xslt_parameters (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:120882)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1364, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:22190)
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'tuple'
```

Comment: Are you trying to serialize `items` to XML? If so XSLT cannot do that for you. XSLT requires XML input.

Comment: But the example mentioned in the lxml website(hyperlinked in the question) converts a python string right ?

Comment: Ah-ha, sorry I didn't see the section in the docs, I updated the URL to point directly to it. The parameters you pass must be unicode strings or bytes. It appears that more complex types like `dict` and `tuple` are not supported. Can you share some sample XSLT too so we're not guessing what you want to do with the parameters? There is probably a more verbose solution, which is normal for XSLT :)

Answer (score 0):

Your reference explains everything very simply. The syntax for parameter passing is like so...

```
>>> result = transform(doc_root, a="'A'")
>>> str(result)
'<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<foo>A</foo>\n'
```

All you have to do is serialise your data into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but i was looking for an answer for the same problem but couldn't find any. What I came up with is to load the xslt as xml and modify it before applying using transform

```
def apply_xslt(xml_file, xslt_file_path, xslt_params):
    try:
        xslt = etree.parse(xslt_file_path)

        for key, value in xslt_params.iteritems():
            xslt.find("//{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}param[@name='" + key + "']").attrib['select'] = value

        transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)

        newdom = transform(xml_file)
        return newdom
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```